# detect smartcard logon or creatential provider for current seesion in NPLogonNotify() windows7

Tags: authentication, windows-7, windows-authentication, smartcard, credential-providers

In Windows 7 64bit, I have registry entry "SmartCardLogonNotify" created as DWORD and set to 1, under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Notify

Now my NPLogonNotify() is called when I logon using smartcard.

So how can I differentiate whether user has logon with username/password or smartcard ?

Every time I receive Kerberos:Interactive logon notifications.

I am new to windows. Please advice.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to unlock the SmartCard with the "password" received from notification. If the unlock is successful, then it is PIN, else password.

Only problem with this approach is, it may lock the SmartCard if the Card is inserted and user logs in with password.